# How to roll back input drivers in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, keyboard, xorg, touchpad

Not knowing Linux has full Wacom tablet support, I thought I found out how to install a driver to enable the buttons on my Bamboo tablet, and I disabled my keyboard and touchpad.

I have the history.log entry for what I did, how do I undo this mess?

```
Start-Date: 2019-05-25  21:18:05

Commandline: apt-get install xorg-input-abi-24

Requested-By: lynda (1000)

Install: libxfont2:amd64 (1:2.0.1-3~ubuntu16.04.3, automatic), xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04:amd64 (2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.1~16.04.2)

**Remove**: xserver-xorg-input-all:amd64 (1:7.7+13ubuntu3.1), xserver-xorg-input-synaptics:amd64 (1.8.2-1ubuntu3), xserver-xorg:amd64 (1:7.7+13ubuntu3.1), xserver-xorg-video-vesa:amd64 (1:2.3.4-1build2), xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 (1:1.0.12-1build2), xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu:amd64 (1.1.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), xserver-xorg-core:amd64 (2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.8), xserver-xorg-video-fbdev:amd64 (1:0.4.4-1build5), ubuntu-desktop:amd64 (1.361.3), xserver-xorg-input-wacom:amd64 (1:0.32.0-0ubuntu3), xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse:amd64 (1:13.1.0-1ubuntu2), xserver-xorg-video-vmware:amd64 (1:13.1.0-2ubuntu3), xserver-xorg-input-evdev:amd64 (1:2.10.1-1ubuntu2), xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 (1:7.7+13ubuntu3.1), xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 (1:7.7.0-1), xorg:amd64 (1:7.7+13ubuntu3.1), xserver-xorg-video-radeon:amd64 (1:7.7.0-1)

End-Date: 2019-05-25  21:18:23
```

I tried dpkg in recovery mode after enabling network support but I got a lot of 522 errors and not all of the packages could be fixed and it said the update was aborted. (The ethernet cable was plugged in. ^_^')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try booting into a tty-shell (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> on login-screen).

From there run

```
sudo apt remove xorg-input-abi-24
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-all ubuntu-desktop  xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-input-kbd xserver-xorg-input-wacom
```

That should undo the involuntary un-install of packages.

Note that Ubuntu should have wacom support out-of-the-box (xserver-xorg-input-wacom should be pre-installed on the desktop version of Ubuntu).

Comment: Pretty sure it's the dumbest thing I've ever done!

Having trouble getting to the tty-shell with ctrl + alt + F2. I don't have a login-screen, I just have a black screen until the desktop loads. (Tried it after the Dell post screen, tried it during the black screen, no luck.)

Comment: It worked! Everything's back to normal and I'll never try to add a driver for something I don't need again! Thanks so much!